# Access a Python Code That is Running

Tags: python

I apologize if this isn't the correct way to word it, but I'm not sure where to start. If this question needs to be reworded, I will definitely do that.

I have just finished writing a piece of code that is collecting data from a variety of servers. It is currently running, and I would like to be able to start writing other pieces of code that can access the data being collected. Obviously I can do this by dumping the data into files, and have my data analysis code read the files stored on disk. However, for some forms of my analysis I would like to have something closer to real time data. Is there a way for me to access the class from my data collection piece of code without explicitly instantiating it? I mean, can I set up one piece of code to start the data collection, and then write other pieces of code later that are able to access the data collection class without stopping and restarting the data collection piece of code?

I hope that makes sense. I realize the data can just be stored to disk, and I could do things like just have my data analysis code search directories for changes. However, I am just curious to know if something like this can be done.

Comment: Do you know about `Apache Kafka` [Tutorial](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: This seems like a `Producer Consumer` problem? See this example [Producer Consumer](http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/)

Comment: That looks along the lines of what I want to do. I hadn't thought about it like that, but I think that's the right idea. My original idea was to just have the data collector run continuously, then send a signal to request a certain amount/type of data from the data collector.

Comment: @python I did not know that I needed to know the information in the link you posted.  I suspect this question will be closed, and thus I would encourage you to write an answer, I think that helps.  If I was not clear - that is probably one of the most useful tidbits I have picked up in a while

Comment: You could rewrite your producer to buffer the incoming data in shared memory (using python's mmap module to create a shared memory segment backed by a temporary file). Then, provided you are careful to avoid concurrency problems (eg using semaphores, mutexes or a readers-writer lock) consumers could read it in real time from there. The data would be in a raw binary format rather than as Python objects (unless you take the performance hit of serializing/deserializing them on the way into/out of shared memory).

Comment: I agree with PyNEwbie. pythons tidbit is worthy of answer points. Post it and I'll accept. If I need to rewrite for clarity, let me know. I would like this to be as helpful to others as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be like a [Producer Consumer](http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/) problem.

> The producer's job is to generate a piece of data, put it into the
>   buffer and start again. At the same time, the consumer is consuming
>   the data (i.e., removing it from the buffer) one piece at a time
>
> The catch here is "At the same time". So, producer and consumer need
>   to run concurrently. Hence we need separate threads for Producer and
>   Consumer.

I am taking code from the above link, you should go through it for extra details.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import random
from Queue import Queue

queue = Queue(10)

class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        nums = range(5)
        global queue
        while True:
            num = random.choice(nums)
            queue.put(num)
            print "Produced", num
            time.sleep(random.random())


class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            num = queue.get()
            queue.task_done()
            print "Consumed", num
            time.sleep(random.random())


ProducerThread().start()
ConsumerThread().start()
```

Explanation :

- We are using a Queue instance(hereafter queue).Queue has a Condition
  and that condition has its lock. You don't need to bother about
  Condition and Lock if you use Queue.
- Producer uses put available on queue to insert data in the queue.
- put() has the logic to acquire the lock before inserting data in
  queue.
- Also put() checks whether the queue is full. If yes, then it calls
  wait() internally and so producer starts waiting.
- Consumer uses get.
- get() acquires the lock before removing data from queue.
- get() checks if the queue is empty. If yes, it puts consumer in
  waiting state.

Comment: As I'm reading this again, I'm wondering if it actually answers my question. Maybe I'm misunderstanding though. Will I have to stop and restart my data collection thread so that my new data analysis thread can access the queue?

Comment: If you need specific answer then you need first write your own code, otherwise it will be difficult.

Comment: I don't see how code will be any more useful than the description here. I want to start one piece of Python code and let it run continuously. While it's running, I want to write another piece of Python code that I can start at any time and have it access the first piece of code without stopping the first piece of code.

Comment: After doing some digging, I think I figured out that I can't do what I want to do. Since Python is an interpretive language, only one active thread can be running because of the GIL in a multithreaded program. So, it seems like the solution to my problem would be to somehow start a new Python interpreter, run code in the new interpreter and somehow access the first interpreter running the data collection process.

Comment: You are right about GIL, but you misunderstood other parts! Read this [Link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil)

Comment: Hm, yet another useful article. Thanks again. I think I misspoke though. I meant that learning about the GIL made me realize that trying to execute code in an interpreter that already has a piece of code running probably won't work, or will be very difficult. Am I wrong in saying this? After doing some more digging on Queue and related topics, I think I want to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading, since multiprocessing seems to open up multiple interpreters. I think this will let me do what I want to do, or at least get closer to it. Am I wrong in thinking like this?